# Refresh after __doPostBack within iframe / jQuery/ASP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, iframe

My question is that I have a page with an iframe that loads an asp form with a __doPostBack() call. Then when  I try to do something in Javascript after "refresh" of the doPostBack(), doesn't nothing.

The __DoPostBack action is called within iframe when I click an a tag. ej:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$plhContent$clsOverview$dgClasses$ctl02$cmdAskRegister','')" class="button" id="ctl00_plhContent_clsOverview_dgClasses_ctl02_cmdAskRegister">Inscripción en Curso</a>
```

I try a lot of solutions I saw on internet but all of there are with asp that I haven't loaded on my HTML. Can I access to the asp events on the iframe?

Iframe load:

```
<div id="gtregistrations.<%=medEntry.getExternalIdentity()%>.<%=medEntry.getType()%>.<%=sLocale%>">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=pref.getGtPath()%>/Liferay/scripts/tls/myregistrations.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var idConvocatoria = 'hola';

        if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
              String.prototype.trim = function() {
                return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
              }
            }

        $(window).load(function() {

            $("#frm_gt_media")
              .contents().find("#ctl00_plhContent_clsOverview_dgClasses")
              .find("[id$=_cmdAskRegister]").click(function() {
                  var oldHref = $(this).attr("href");
                  var idConvocatoria = $(this).parent().parent().siblings(":first").text().trim();

                  if (confirm("¿Necesita desplazamiento para el curso?")) {
                        //Logica ejecutar formulario y registrar
                        AUI().use(
                                  'aui-aria',
                                  'aui-dialog',
                                  'node',
                                  'aui-overlay-manager',
                                  'dd-constrain',
                                  function(A) {
                                        var dialog = new A.Dialog(
                                          {
                                            centered: true,
                                            height: 700,
                                            title: 'Solicitud Desplazamiento',
                                            width: 1024

                                          }
                                        ).render();
                                        dialog.plug(
                                          A.Plugin.IO,
                                          {
                                            autoLoad: false,
                                            uri: '<%=solicitudPortlet%>+&idConvocatoria='+ $("#frm_gt_media").contents().find("#ctl00_plhContent_clsOverview_dgClasses").find("[id$=_cmdAskRegister]").parent().parent().siblings(":first").text().trim()
                                          }
                                        );

                                        dialog.io.start();
                                      }
                                    );
                    } else {
                        //logica solo registrar y refresh?

                    }
              });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: not sure i undestand what you want to achieve and when exactly?

Comment: I just want to do something just after of doPostBack is executed. To change the functionallity of a button of the form.

Comment: where is `doPostBack` code and when is it executed, it is not in your question, add it please

Comment: You can assign an onload event on the iframe, but that will fire anytime the iframe loads.  Not just when postback occurs.

Comment: A lot of thanks @HaukurHaf this works perfect. Post your comment like response if you want and I mark as solved.

Comment: Cool, just posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign an onload event on the iframe, but that will fire anytime the iframe loads. Not just when postback occurs.